# package forward low performance and low forward speed in using Ubuntu as router

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, iptables, ip-forward

I have built a router based on **Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1**(kernel: 4.15.0-32-generic x86_64).

I followed this guide https://killtacknine.com/building-an-ubuntu-16-04-router-part-1-network-interfaces/ .

But after I had really tried it, I found something wrong.

**The network is abnormal.**

My ISP is China Telecom that my bandwidth is 200 Mbps down & 20 Mbps up.

I test my bandwidth in Ubuntu on speedtest.net. It reached my bandwidth.
But if I test it in a Windows host which connect Ubuntu. It just reached 10Mbps / 20 Mbps(Yes,up is faster than down).(They tested on a same node)

I have installed the newest ethernet driver from Realtek.

But if I use Chrome on Windows host to download a iso file from the nearest university's mirror, the download speed would be very ok.

I have tried to pppoe by my real router, it could also give me a nice speed.

file `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  network 10.0.0.0
  netmask 255.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
  bridge_ports enp1s0 enp2s0 enp4s0
  bridge_stp on
```

command `ifconfig`:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:141  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:01:41  txqueuelen 1000  (以太网)
        RX packets 82694  bytes 141679903 (141.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 96992  bytes 63026899 (63.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:01:41  txqueuelen 1000  (以太网)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:01:42  txqueuelen 1000  (以太网)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:01:43  txqueuelen 1000  (以太网)
        RX packets 132766  bytes 64971378 (64.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 376  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 144862  bytes 147788638 (147.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:01:44  txqueuelen 1000  (以太网)
        RX packets 80626  bytes 85799840 (85.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45697  bytes 30678421 (30.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (本地环回)
        RX packets 56  bytes 5804 (5.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56  bytes 5804 (5.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 125.xxx.xxx.61  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 125.xxx.xxx.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (点对点协议)
        RX packets 132010  bytes 61697165 (61.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143928  bytes 144553030 (144.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In the above `enp3s0` is WAN port which support `ppp0`(pppoe).

`enp1s0`,`enp2s0`,`enp4s0` are LAN ports, `br0`is bridge port.

You could notice that `enp3s0`'s RX have dropped some packages, but I don't know how would this happen.

file `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.core.default_qdisc = fq
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = bbr
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.core.netdev_budget=1000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=1000
```

Netdata alarmed to me that `number of times, during the last 10min, ksoftirq ran out of sysctl net.core.netdev_budget or time slice, with work remaining (this can be a cause for dropped packets)`, so I have increased `net.core.netdev_budget` and `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` .But it's useless.

Could anyone tell me how to fix it ? I just want to get a normal network speed.

Thanks everyone who answered or noticed this question in advance.

**ADD**:

When I test by Speedtest:

Some system information.

[top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSlpA.png)

[free -m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paTmp.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added ``top`` and ``free`` information.

Comment: Are you in Power Saving Mode?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

It is `network-manager` which I use to init my pppoe connection.

I don't know why `network-manager` would be like this. But it is he who caused the issue.

To solve it:

```
# delete my older pppoe(dsl) connection
nm-connection-editor
# configure new connection by pppoeconf
pppoeconf
# disable network-manager due to it is not useful to me
systemctl disable network-manager
systemctl start network-manager
```